# WPF DataGrid with IsAsync data binding don't preserve values when scrolling and sorting

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-core

First, this is a gif demonstrating the problem:

[image]

As you can see the UPDATED value that takes time to be generated is recalculated each time we scroll or sort by column.

This is a condensed version of my XAML code:

```xml
<DataGrid Grid.Row="0" CanUserResizeRows="False" CanUserAddRows="false" Name="DgPackages" AutoGenerateColumns="False" BorderBrush="#B9B9B9" BorderThickness="0 0 0 3">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="?" Width="50" HeaderStyle="{StaticResource CenterAlignmentColumnHeaderStyle}" SortMemberPath="IsSelected">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <CheckBox Padding="0" IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Width="170" Binding="{Binding Name}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Updated" Width="90" Binding="{Binding IsUpdated, IsAsync=True}" CanUserSort="False" HeaderStyle="{StaticResource CenterAlignmentColumnHeaderStyle}" CellStyle="{StaticResource CenterAlignmentColumnCellStyle}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Description" Width="*" Binding="{Binding Info}" IsReadOnly="True" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

And this a condensed version of my C# code:

```cs
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    var pkgs = new List<Package> { 
        new Chromium(), new Firefox(), new Chromium(), new Firefox(),
        new Chromium(), new Firefox(), new Chromium(), new Firefox(),
        new Chromium(), new Firefox(), new Chromium(), new Firefox(),
    };
    DgPackages.ItemsSource = pkgs;
}
```

Finally, the instantiated classes:

```cs
abstract class Package
{
    public bool IsSelected { get; set; } = false;
    public bool IsUpdated => GetAvailableVersion().Result <= GetInstalledVersion().Result;
    public abstract string Name { get; }
    public abstract string Info { get; }
    protected abstract Task<int> GetAvailableVersion();
    protected abstract Task<int> GetInstalledVersion();
}
```

```cs
class Chromium : Package
{
    public override string Name => "Chromium";
    public override string Info => "Chromium ipsum";
    protected override async Task<int> GetAvailableVersion()
    {
        await Task.Delay(200);
        return 1;
    }
    protected override async Task<int> GetInstalledVersion()
    {
        await Task.Delay(200);
        return 1;
    }
}
```

The Firefox class is almost the same as Chromium.

Do you have an idea how to fix it?

Comment: A property is not supposed to kick-off an asynchronous operation. That's not what the `IsAsync` property is for. The getter of *each* `Package` will be called.

Comment: hmm but you never cache your GetAvailableVersion and  GetInstalledVersion ... so obviously every time getter IsUpdated  is called, they are called again ... I don't get it what is confusing you

Comment: Caching is almost solving the issue, thanks ! But I always get micro delay when scrolling or sorting by column.

Comment: Due to virtualization when you move slider then visible elements are bind to different elements, and getter is called. But don't turn off virtualization, caching is better option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A property is not supposed to kick-off an asynchronous operation. That's not what the `IsAsync` property is for.

The getter of each `Package` will be called as the item is scrolled into view. If you don't want to recalculate the value, you should catch it:

```
private bool? _isUpdated;
public bool IsUpdated
{
    get
    {
        if (_isUpdated.HasValue)
            return _isUpdated.Value;
        _isUpdated = GetAvailableVersion().Result <= GetInstalledVersion().Result;
        return _isUpdated.Value;
    }
}
```